# SQL Developer import scientific notation error

Tags: oracle, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to import a text file to an already-existing table with SQL Developer 18.3 on Windows.

I have a column with data type `float(126)` and I want to store very small numbers in it. The data is in scientific notation (e.g. 1.5e-82) in the text file, but the importer doesn't accept this data. The status is "Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column.".

[image: error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XCjy.png)

When I try to add one row with insert, it works so the problem seems to be the import. Should I use a different type?

(The language of the computer is English and it accepts basic decimal numbers so the decimal point (instead of comma) shouldn't be the problem.)

Comment: *" the importer doesn't accept this data"* - please clarify this statement. Do you have a text file with the values in scientific notation (that is  `'1.5e-82'`)? Or a file with very long decimal numbers that you want to store in the database in scientific notation (`0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015`)?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, the values are in scientific notation in the text file. The error status is: "Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column."

Comment: You can inline the image so that it is more readable.

Comment: Interesting, possibly looks lilke a bug or oversight. As a workaround you can change the import method to 'Insert Script' and then run the generated script, but that doesn't seem ideal, particualrly if youre source file is large.

Comment: @AlexPoole an oversight...of sorts. this might be the first time I've seen someone want to do this - but they should be able to. the INSERT SCRIPT method is the way to go. If the source file is large, the ideal methods are EXTERNAL TABLE or SQL*Loader.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is slightly odder than I thought when I commented. When I recreated it I went back and tried the 'Insert Script' option, and that didn't complain. But I also tried picking SQL*Loader, which also errored; and external table, which did not (but needs the file to be on the DB server, of course).

But @thatjeffsmith implied that SQL*Loader worked, so I tried that again, and... it does, but not on the first attempt.

If you launch the data import wizard and click through the options, whichever import type you select you get that error (still using 'Insert'):

[image]

But click the Back button to go back to the previous stage:

[image]

and then click the Next button to go forward again:

[image]

and now it doesn't error, and you can carry on and successfully complete the import.